# How to calculate using Column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have Creating more than 10000 lines Using SQL Server.I inserted Many values.Now i want sum of Total based Expensive type value .

```
   ExpenseTypeCode      ExpenseType
    700300              Meals - FBR Only
    700450              Taxis/Parking/Tolls
    700450              Taxis/Parking/Tolls
    700300              Meals - FBR Only
    700300              Meals - FBR Only
```

i have this two fields and values.Now i want Sum of total using Expense type value .I want  separate Total Like `Taxis/Parking/Tolls` total .how can  calculate  total based column value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply you can do like this

```
select ExpenseType,Total=Sum(ExpenseTypeCode) from YourTable
group by ExpenseType
```